# Error Running Jupyter Notebook on Pycharm

Tags: python, windows, pycharm, jupyter-notebook

This is my first stack overflow question, so I hope it is comprehensible.
I have a neural net from a couple of years ago on a flash drive. I made it on a windows computer and am now trying to run it on a mac. When I try to run the program it asked for my token, I canceled and clicked run jupyter notebook in the pop up (as was directed at https://www.jetbrains.com/help/pycharm/running-ipython-notebook-cells.html). But when I clicked run jupyter notebook it gave me this error:

> Error running 'Building Neural Networks': Cannot run program 
>       "C:/Users/*myusername*/AppData/Local/Programs/Python/Python36- 
>       32/python.exe" (in directory "/Volumes/*myflashdrive*/Building Neural 
>       Networks"): error=2, No such file or directory

it seems like there is some error because it was made on a windows, but I can't find where I can fix it. I am able to use jupyter notebook on projects not from the flash drive. Thanks.

Comment: That error message has a space in the path `C:/Users/myusername/AppData/Local/Programs/Python/Python36- 32/python.exe` (after the hyphen) which I am very sure should not be there. If you have reported it accurately then you need to fix your Jupyter configuration so that it knows where Python36 really is.

Comment: Thanks! How do you fix the Jupyter configuration?

Comment: No idea. I don't use it myself, I'm just pointing out where the problem seems to be. That is why this is a comment not an answer.